# PHP generate the the Particular NUmber Range using LOOP?

Tags: php

I want to generate the number range like

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06
```

therefore i make the script like

```
for ($x = 00; $x <= 06; $x++)
{
echo $x:
}
```

but it give the output like

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

How to get the number series like 00 01 02 03 04 05 06.plz help me on this .
Using only by loop.

Comment: Replace your `echo` with `echo str_pad($x, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: you can use `sprintf()`

Comment: ... or `printf('%02d', $x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leading zero in  ints or numbers doesnt meant anything..

```
00 = 0 and 01 = 1 so on..
```

So we need to format the output in display

what you will need is a sprintf function

```
for ($x = 00; $x <= 06; $x++)
{
   printf("%02d", $x);
}
```

Comment: It's `printf`, not `sprintf`.

Comment: @raina77ow its basically the same.

Comment: No, it's not, and it's not that difficult to check it actually. This code won't output anything, as `sprintf` only returns the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the extra "0" during the echo part :

```
for ($x = 0; $x < WHATSOEVER; ++$x) {
  echo ($x < 10) ? '0' . $x : $x;
}
```